# Как убрать бесконечные логи в eclipse при подлючении реального устройства

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

При подлючении реального устройства android для тестирования к eclipse с недавнего времени начал заполнятся LogCat огромным количеством беспрерывных логов (примерно 100 в секунду). Большинство из них под тегом NuCachedSource2. Как можно от этого избавиться?

[image: логи]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо составить фильтр, убирающий из окна логов всё лишнее. Для этого в поле ввода над логами вставьте строку вида:

```
tag:^(?!TAG)
```

т.е. чтобы отфильтровать все сообщения с тегом `NuCachedSource2` используйте

```
tag:^(?!NuCachedSource2)
```

В качестве бонуса вот вам собранная мною долгими стараниями строка для фильтра:

> tag:^(?!TelephonyManager) tag:^(?!charger_monitor) tag:^(?!WeatherReflect) tag:^(?!PowerManagerService) tag:^(?!WifiController) tag:^(?!qazwsx) tag:^(?!NotificationServiceEx) tag:^(?!KeyguardUpdateMonitor) tag:^(?!WifiManager) tag:^(?!VideoCapabilities) tag:^(?!AudioFlinger) tag:^(?!qdlights) tag:^(?!LEDHandler) tag:^(?![SystemUI]LGPowerUI) tag:^(?!WeatherTheme) tag:^(?!linker) tag:^(?!System.out) tag:^(?!sensors_hal_Time) tag:^(?!SwipeRefreshLayout) tag:^(?!LGMtpServerJNI) tag:^(?!PhoneWindow) tag:^(?!ContextHelper) tag:^(?!NotificationManager) tag:^(?!BindingManager) tag:^(?!AwContents) tag:^(?!TouchFlickNoti) tag:^(?!skia) tag:^(?!VelocityTracker) tag:^(?!SurfaceTextureClient) tag:^(?!GraphicBuffer) tag:^(?!InputMethodManager) tag:^(?!AbsListView) tag:^(?!AudioSystemEx) tag:^(?!MediaRecorderEx) tag:^(?!Adreno-EGL) tag:^(?!LGMtpDatabaseJNI) tag:^(?!MediaProfilesEx-JNI) tag:^(?!Atlas) tag:^(?!SurfaceControlEx) tag:^(?!MediaPlayerEx-jni) tag:^(?!BubblePopupHelper) tag:^(?!dalvikvm) tag:^(?!libEGL) tag:^(?!Open) tag:^(?!Google) tag:^(?!resour) tag:^(?!Chore) tag:^(?!EGL) tag:^(?!SocketStream) tag:^(?!WifiStateMachine) tag:^(?!chromium) tag:^(?!audio_hw_primary) tag:^(?!InputEventReceiver) tag:^(?!ActivityManager) tag:^(?!AudioManagerAndroid) tag:^(?!LibraryLoader) tag:^(?!WebViewFactory) tag:^(?!JavaBinder) tag:^(?!art) tag:^(?!ViewRootImpl) tag:^(?!InputMethodManagerService) tag:^(?!ACDB-LOADER) tag:^(?!WindowManager) tag:^(?!WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider) tag:^(?!GCM) tag:^(?!CalendarProvider2) tag:^(?!View) tag:^(?!libc-netbsd) tag:^(?!Timeline) tag:^(?!CliptrayUtils) tag:^(?!BrowserStartupController)

Comment: Спасибо, фильтрация работает. Логи с введенными мною тегами не показываются, но сами логи продолжают писаться и за минуту набирается несколько тысяч, это разве нормально при отсутствии работы с самим устройством?

Comment: ИМХО, считаю что нормально. Лично меня вполне устраивает их фильтрация. Дебажить не мешает.

Comment: Кстати, если ответ решил заявленную в вопросе проблему - то хорошим тоном на сайте считается отметить его принятым (нажав на галочку слева от ответа). =)

Answer (score 0):

Помогла обычная перезагрузка смартфона, оказывается в процессах висело очень много созданных собою же процессов при изучении данной темы(я забыл их отключить, они работали постоянно и передавали логи).